# Is every martingale a semi-martingale?

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis

This is a question I am having related to my research.
Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

> A semi-martingale is defined as $M + A$, where *M* is a martingale and *A* is a process of bounded variation. So $M = M + 0$, where $A = 0$. Can we conclude that a martingale is a semi-martingale this way?

Also is it correct to say that a martingale multiplied by a process of bounded variation, (M*A) is a semi martingale. I think it is. Need some help with proving it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, and the given argument shows it.  Why would you doubt it?

Comment: Certainly no variation at all is bounded variation!

Comment: Nate, I was Just making sure. Thanks.